# ${}$How do static point charges exert the same force on each other?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law

How can two different charges exert same force.
I want to ask is this proportionality to product of charges was found by experiments or what?why is it product and not addition?ie sum of charges.
And why the Coulomb’s law not tell us mathematically that there are two forces one exerted by each charge on the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And why the Coulomb’s law not tell us mathematically that there are two forces one exerted by each charge on the other

Because Coulomb's law is prescription for a force inside framework of mechanics, that already has a law telling us there are two forces. Stating it again would just be a repetition.

> Then I want to ask is this proportionality was found by experiments or what?why is it product and not addition?

For one, if it would have been sum, then two equal in magnitude but opposite charges would cancel each other out and there would not be any force between the two particles. This is not what we observe. We observe two electrons repel each other, we also observe two protons repel each other, but we do observe one electron and one proton to attract each other.

And everything in physics was found by experiments. There have been instances when theory predicted something before experiment was conducted and experiment confirmed the prediction, but before experiment it is just an educated guess. There has been theoretical predictions that were refuted by experiment also. So before experiment, the best we can do is educated guess, and only after it we have a discovery.

Comment: Can you tell me where can I find this experiment done to conclude that it’s a product. Can I find it on internet.

Comment: “inside framework of mechanics “ means? I didn’t get that .

Comment: @cOnnectOrTR12 I have no reference to particular experiment. Mechanics framework is framework in which we are formulating our mechanical laws. I.e. we assume 3D Euclidean space with absolute time, 3 Newton laws of motion, Galilean invariance and so on. But it does not tells us anything about interaction themselves, only in what form should we formulate them (i.e. as forces) and what do with them once we have them (i.e. that forces determine accelerations)

Comment: We don’t put charges with their signs in Coulomb’s law. So I don’t see why there would be no force.

Answer (score 0):

if we accept that a force is something that causes a change in momevent, and that opossite but equal in magnitude forces cancel, we can use some thought experiment Plank wrote: that if we have two particules connected rigidly with constant distance, and if the forces between them were not equal, then the system would start to move in the direction of the greater force and would continue to accelerate without end, that kind of thing is nevertheless impossible, but illustrates the fact the forces are equal.